# Eric Martin's SimpleModal and Flv Player

Tags: jquery

Am I able to embed a flash player in an Eric Martin  jquery simple modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Pop the FLV player into a DIV and make the DIV the target of the modal function.